# How do I get rid of black spots on my aloe vera plant?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, aloe

[image: Aloe Vera]
The Aloe Vera plant's leaves have developed few black spots. How do I get rid of these black spots? Is it caused by Fungi (Phytophthora, Alternaria alternata)?

I also notice that the plant is weak and bent. It's roots are coming out and it is not able to support itself.

Comment: My Aloe vera also has black spots, but the size is very very small.

Comment: My Aloe Vera also initially had very small black spots which later developed into larger spots. I think it is making it weak.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs at [gardening.se]. Please don't cross-post, instead delete this question and re-ask it there.

Comment: @MattDMo OR Moderators, Please consider migrating it to Gardening & landscaping SE instead of closing it.